# What is the main difference between desire capabilities and Firefox option in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

//1-What is the difference between DesiredCapabilities and 
   FirefoxOptions ?
   // 2-What is the best practice among those two and why ?

```
   FirefoxOptions optionsff = new FirefoxOptions();
   optionsff.setProfile(profile);
   driver= new FirefoxDriver({path to web driver},optionsff);

   //----------------------------------------------------------

   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(false);
   dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
   Webdriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score 0):

DesiredCapabilities is deprecated unless you are using it to instantiate a RemoteWebDriver instance.  The new {DriverName}Options is what to use moving forwards.

A lot of the deprecated methods will be removed when Selenium 4 goes live so it's best to start moving over to the new methods as soon as you can.